# Lambda Query Issues between Accounts

Tags: python, aws-lambda

I am struggling to workout what i have done wrong.
I have 2 accounts:

Account A - 11111111111

Account B - 22222222222

Account A is our login account, it holds all the user details
Account B is our product account.

I want to run my Lambda in Account B and report on data in Account A.  Currently, when i run the lambda i am getting the following error:

```
An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListUsers operation: User: arn:aws:sts::2222222222:assumed-role/svc_pct_iam_lambda_role/unusedaccount_lambda_function is not authorized to perform: iam:ListUsers on resource: arn:aws:iam::2222222222:user/: ClientError
```

The error i think is that its using the current BotoClient in the account the lambda is running in and not where i have allowed access to. So it is querying account 222222222 and not 1111111

Account A has the following role and policy

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "svc_pct_iam_lambda_role" {
  name = "svc_pct_iam_lambda_role"

  assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Sid": ""
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy" "svc_pct_iam_lambda_access_policy" {
  name = "svc_pct_iam_lambda_access_policy"
  role = "${aws_iam_role.svc_pct_iam_lambda_role.id}"

  policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::2222222222:role/svc_pct_iam_lambda_role"
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}

resource "aws_iam_policy" "svc_pct_iam_lambda_policy" {
  name = "svc_pct_iam_lambda_policy"

  policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": [
        "iam:ListUsers",
        "iam:ListMFADevices",
        "iam:ListVirtualMFADevices",
        "SNS:Publish",
        "iam:ListAccessKeys",
        "iam:ListUserPolicies",
        "iam:ListGroupsForUser"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "role-attach-svc-pct-iam-lambda-role" {
  role       = "${aws_iam_role.svc_pct_iam_lambda_role.name}"
  policy_arn = "${aws_iam_policy.svc_pct_iam_lambda_policy.arn}"
}
```

The policy in Account B where the Lambda resides is:

```
"resource "aws_iam_role" "svc_pct_iam_lambda_role" {
  name = "svc_pct_iam_lambda_role"

  assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Sid": ""
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy" "svc_pct_iam_lambda_policy" {
  name = "svc_pct_iam_lambda_policy"
  role = "${aws_iam_role.svc_pct_iam_lambda_role.id}"

  policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::1111111111:role/svc_pct_iam_lambda_role"
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}
```

The lambda is

```
import boto3
import datetime
from dateutil.tz import tzutc
def lambda_handler(context,event):

    resource = boto3.resource('iam')
    client = boto3.client("iam")

    today = datetime.datetime.now()

    for user in resource.users.all():
        if user.password_last_used is not None:
            delta = (today - user.password_last_used.replace(tzinfo=None)).days
            if delta >= 60:
                print("Username: ",[user.user_name], delta)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the AWS Lambda function to be able to access resources in Account-A, it needs to **Assume the IAM Role** from Account-A.

So, it will:

- Use the IAM Role from Account-B
- To call `AssumeRole()`
- Which returns a set of temporary credentials
- These temporary credentials can then be used to make API calls to Account-A

Here's some sample code from [Switching to an IAM Role (AWS API) - AWS Identity and Access Management](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_switch-role-api.html):

```py
import boto3

# create an STS client object that represents a live connection to the STS service
sts_client = boto3.client('sts')

# Call the assume_role method of the STSConnection object and pass the role ARN and a role session name.
assumed_role_object=sts_client.assume_role(
    RoleArn="arn:aws:iam::account-of-role-to-assume:role/name-of-role",
    RoleSessionName="AssumeRoleSession1"
)

# From the response that contains the assumed role, get the temporary 
# credentials that can be used to make subsequent API calls
credentials=assumed_role_object['Credentials']

# Use the temporary credentials that AssumeRole returns to make a 
# connection to Amazon S3  
s3_resource=boto3.resource(
    's3',
    aws_access_key_id=credentials['AccessKeyId'],
    aws_secret_access_key=credentials['SecretAccessKey'],
    aws_session_token=credentials['SessionToken'],
)

# Use the Amazon S3 resource object that is now configured with the 
# credentials to access your S3 buckets. 
for bucket in s3_resource.buckets.all():
    print(bucket.name)
```